# The driver executable does not exist

Tags: java, selenium

Iam getting error message like:

```
The driver executable does not exist: P:\workspace\portalindia_Automation\Drivers\chromedriver.exe
```

But I have initialized the driver in global properties as below:

```
ChromeDriverPath=C:\\Users\\626461\\git\\portalindia_Automation\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe
```

Please help me solving the error

Comment: welcome to SO!! please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly, provide the code trials and errors

Comment: Looks like a typo in your `ChromeDriverPath`. It is not pointing to the same directory that the error message does.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting it says that `chromedriver.exe` is not present on that location. check if the driver is present or not on that location.

Download your driver as per your chrome version

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Do it like below:

```
String ChromeDriverPath="C:\Users\626461\git\portalindia_Automation\Drivers\chromedriver.exe";

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",ChromeDriverPath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
driver.get("https://google.com");
```